# Export two modules of same project separately?

Tags: web-component, stenciljs

In Stenciljs is it possible to export two modules of same project separately?

I want to create host which can have multiple web components from same project and when required we can import it in any other projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tsconfig` option in `stencil.config.ts` to decide which `tsconfig.json` to use for the build (e. g. based on an environment variable), and then have different `include` or `exclude` settings in those tsconfigs, to decide which modules should be part of the build.